# What is wrong with this CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

it says:Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

```
with address_cte (id,Street,City,[State],ZIP,Country)
as
(
Select p.id, a.Street,a.City,a.[State],a.ZIP,a.Country
from People p
left join Address a on p.id = a.PeopleId
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use a `select`, `insert` , `delete` or `update` statement after a `cte`. It can't exist stand-alone.

Comment: Thanks I was going crazy